# set a Controller in image map clickable area

Tags: android

I use image map class for my app but only now i have clickable area.
how i can set a Controller in clickable area withe image map Syntax.

```
    <area name="show" shape="rect" coords="119,105,444,194" id="@+id/area1001"/>

    <area name="back" shape="rect" coords="310,284,371,343" id="@+id/area1002"/>        
    <area name="enter" shape="rect" coords="309,358,370,417" id="@+id/area1003"/>
    <area name="up" shape="rect" coords="415,283,476,342" id="@+id/area1004"/>
    <area name="down" shape="rect" coords="415,357,476,416" id="@+id/area1005"/>        

    <area name="aux" shape="rect" coords="115,294,188,321" id="@+id/area1006"/>
    <area name="trip" shape="rect" coords="115,336,188,363" id="@+id/area1007"/>
    <area name="alarm" shape="rect" coords="116,378,189,405" id="@+id/area1008"/>        

    <area name="clear" shape="rect" coords="309,510,370,569" id="@+id/area1009"/>        
    <area name="mod" shape="rect" coords="414,511,475,570" id="@+id/area10010"/>
```